# Genesys Logic, Inc. USB 2.0 33-in-1 Card Reader (internal)

Tags: usb, card-reader

I've just plugged in a internal usb card reader

```
Genesys Logic, Inc. USB 2.0 33-in-1 Card Reader
```

$lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0710 **Genesys Logic, Inc. USB 2.0 33-in-1 Card Reader**
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 090c:0203 Feiya Technology Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 15ca:00c3 Textech International Ltd. Mini Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 413c:2003 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard
```

But when I plug in a card nothing happens.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi Software Development, are you still looking for an answer?

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, I had a couple of those "33-in-1" card readers. They never worked in Linux, Windows or anything with electricity. I am not saying all but from 7 I tested 4 had the same issue. Of those 4 only one slot of SD worked, the rest did not. So maybe the problem might be the device and not Linux. I suggest to test it on Windows and if it is bad, buy a new one and test it on the place you are buying it from.

Answer (score 0):

They *can* work, all that is needed in most modern Ubuntu/debian distros is:

open up a terminal and run:

```
 apt-get install sg3-utils
```

If that doesn't get it to work, look at http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~ggbaker/personal/cf-linux

Comment: `sg3-utils` doesn't contain any system integration, so just installing it won't change anything...