# USB Memory card reader does not work

Tags: card-reader

It appears:

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 035: ID 05e3:0710 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB 2.0 33-in-1 Card Reader
```

But when I insert a mini SD card in the reader, nothing happens. How to solve this and read the card?

Comment: The same problem here, but in my case, my Bus 006 Device 003: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader seems to be able to read ONLY SD Cards in the slot provided for both SD and Mini SD cards. I think it is a hardware limitation. I hope somebody drop a good answer.

Comment: post `sudo fdisk -l`. I don't want to discourage you, but have [a look](http://askubuntu.com/questions/97499/genesys-logic-inc-usb-2-0-33-in-1-card-reader-internal). Is the card reader working on Windows or Mac?

Comment: Disco /dev/sda: 128.0 GB, 128035676160 bytes
255 cabeças, 63 setores/trilhas, 15566 cilindros, total de 250069680 setores
Unidades = setores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamanho do setor (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamanho da E/S (mínimo/ideal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Identificador do disco: 0x00033a58

Comment: Dispositivo Boot Início Fim Blocos Id Sistema
/dev/sda1   *        2048   242997247   121497600   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       242999294   250068991     3534849    5  Estendida
/dev/sda5       242999296   250068991     3534848   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Comment: Disco /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 cabeças, 63 setores/trilhas, 243201 cilindros, total de 3907029168 setores
Unidades = setores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamanho do setor (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
Tamanho da E/S (mínimo/ideal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Identificador do disco: 0x000dab95

Comment: Dispositivo Boot Início Fim Blocos Id Sistema
/dev/sdb1            2048  3907028991  1953513472   83  Linux

Answer (score 0):

It may seem obvious, but I have had card readers that worked intermittently.  If the card reader is portable than try it in a different machine (verses one that is mounted in a 3 1/2 inch bay on the machine).  Sometimes the mini card holder is not making a connection.  Try to insert the mini USB in a different holder.  If it is a multiple card reader with a USB dongle than try a different one, or a different USB port.  Please let me know if that solves it and what kind of reader you have!

Comment: this card reader works perfectly in windows. Each type of card appears as a hard drive in windows.